# How can I use an alias for a category?

Tags: templating

I have a category group called `country`, with each category being the name of a country.  I used the full name of the country.
I realize I might want to use each country's 2-digit code.  For example, AU for Australia.

**How might I implement the abbreviations to associate with the category?**

Put another way, how can I use the 2-digit code as an alias for the full country name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the category handle.

If that doesn't suit your requirements, you can associate custom fields with categories, same as you can with entries.